# how to execute a command before the docker run command in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a file in the `/vault/secrets/some_file` path shared through a volume mount in my docker container that contains:

```
export AA="aaa"
```

so if I run a `kubectl exec MY_POD -- cat /vault/secrets/some_file` it returns `export AA="aaa"`

I want to run this before the main container is started so that the value of AA can be used as an environment variable inside the container.

What I could do was that I could add this to my deployment.yaml file under containers

```
          command:
            ['sh', '-c']
          args:
            ['source /vault/secrets/some_file && <entrypoint script>']
```

But the problem is that I don't have any .
In the images that are being pulled, the entry point or CMD is included inside the docker image.

Note that I don't have any control over the docker image being pulled. It might be the hello world image or any other image that I do not have access to its entrypoint. I am asking for a solution that would work with an arbitrary image.

Is there a way I can do this without having to change the docker images entrypoint script?

Comment: I'm a little confused -- you said "I have an initContainer", but then you say, "I want to run this before the main container is started". An initContainer **does** run before the main container is started.

Comment: the initcontainer puts the secret file there. its responsibility is done

Comment: If your images don't have an entrypoint script, they still have a default command. Your proposed solution (`source /vault/secrets/some_file && run-existing-command`) would work in that situation as well.

Comment: the problem is that I don't have control over the image. the image being pulled is out of my control. I dont know the entry point of the image

Comment: This doesn't require any control over the image; it only requires that you control the pod manifest. If you're asking for a solution that will work with an *arbitrary* image, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: yes, I am asking for a solution for an arbitrary image that I dont know its entrypoint

Answer (score 0):

I've read all your comments, but I can't add a comment because of my reputation

You want to run your scripts between

1. Run init containers
2. [ your command ] <-
3. Run Docker Entrypoint scripts

Right?

If you can use docker command and you have pulled image, you can know what is entrypoint by using

```
sudo docker inspect [image name or id]
sudo docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Entrypoint}}' [image_name]
```

And if entrypoint looks like 'entrypoint.sh or run.sh' (file type)

```
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash [image/id] 
find / -name entrypoint.sh
cat /path/to/entrypoint.sh
```

And now, I think you have 2 solutions

1. you have found how entrypoint looks like, so use your command you have done

   ```
      command:
        ['sh', '-c']
      args:
        ['source /vault/secrets/some_file && <entrypoint script>']
   ```
2. build new image by using pulled image

Dockerfile example

```
FROM [your arbitrary image name]
COPY your-script.sh /your-script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./your-script.sh"]
CMD ["<original-entrypoint>", "<args>"]
```

Then use `sudo docker build -t [your image name]` and use it with kubernetes yaml

I wish it would be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below approach

```
command:
  ['sh', '-c']
args:
  ['export $(xargs < /vault/secrets/some_file) && <entrypoint script>']
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use an initContainer.

this spec will create a single pod, that runs two instances of the same image (following your question, it is using the "hello world" image); first you use an initContainer to grab the output of the first run, saves the output into an env variable that it feeds into the next run of a second "hello world" container.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: main-container
    image: hello-world
    env:
    - name: HELLO_WORLD_OUTPUT
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.annotations['hello-world-output']
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - echo "Hello World output: $HELLO_WORLD_OUTPUT"

  initContainers:
  - name: init-container
    image: hello-world
    env:
    - name: HELLO_WORLD_OUTPUT
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.annotations['hello-world-output']
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - echo "Hello World" > /tmp/hello-world-output
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /tmp

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  restartPolicy: Never
```